# How to seal garage floor edge

Tags: flooring

The wall sits on the wood which sits on a rough 2" concrete block.

How should I cover this edge so that I have a single clean surface from the floor to the wall?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In all cases like this, I have this covered with a durable paintable material. In your case I would use a 1X PVC material to cover from the floor to the top of the 2X plate and another piece of PVC or 1X wood to cover the top of the plate and PVC edge and paint it all.

[image]

Comment: What do you call that type of floor edge I have? And what form of PVC do you use?

Comment: The picture does not show everything I need to see. If there is a block (CMU) wall and the concrete is poured up to it, that is typical. I do not see any vertical joints showing at 16" above the concrete floor, so it may be a concrete wall instead of CMU (Concrete Masonry Unit). What your slab is called is a slab on grade. I do not know what to call the floor edge you may be referring to but the wall may have a ledge that is possibly supporting the edge of the floor slab, though not necessarily. The type of PVC is a rot proof exterior trim available at lumber stores. In the same shape as wood.